# Two e-commerce in two different folders of the same domain

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, multisite, add-submenu-page

I need to create two e-commerce with woocommerce, one in the main directory of my site in Italian and English for online sales in Europe, and one in a subfolder or subdirectory exclusive for Switzerland in CHF with differentiated prices. I would like to know if you have to install wordpress also in the subfolder, so a wordpress installation for each woocommerce plug or can you manage the two online shops even with a single installation? And in any case, what do you recommend for a better performance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you really need 2 WooCommerce instances, you need 2 WordPress instances. However, I presume you don't really need that and just make your shop location-aware (and display different stuff depending on it).

Comment: I actually need two different trading platforms because prices are different, orders are handled differently and shipments start from different places.

Comment: Okay, what I missed in my first comment: You can create a [MultiSite](https://wordpress.org/support/article/create-a-network/), meaning you'll have one WordPress instance that acts as multiple. So you could set up sub-sites for each store, each with their own WooCommerce and custom settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to know if you have to install wordpress also in the subfolder, so a wordpress installation for each woocommerce plug or can you manage the two online shops even with a single installation?

Both options work, either 2 installations of WordPress with WooCommerce installed, or a single installation of WordPress set up as a multisite.

Neither will give a performance benefit over the other, but the multisite install will be simpler to maintain

Comment: Thanks Tom, At the end I chose to install two wordpress instances. I'll be more free to install different plug-in on both. One must be multilangual, the other only in english and the currency only CHF. I'm not very expert, so I think it will be easier to manage separately. I don't know if it would be possible to do the same with a multisite.

Comment: That shouldn't prevent a multisite from working. Keep in mind though this isn't a discussion forum, you need to be able to mark an answer as the correct answer. If mine answers your question well consider checking the tick under the voting controls to set it as the accepted answer